# For Loop in Django template just repeats the last value in dictionary

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am receiving data from an API that I am looping over in my template. Every value comes out fine but the date.

Because the template cant format the date as a string I formatted it in my view (shown below). But now when I pass that datetime variable into my template it just shows the same date for each iteration, every other value is correct.

How can I get the dates iterated over properly?

Thanks!

```py
    for game in games:
        date = game['schedule']['date']
        datetime_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        game_date = datetime_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
        game_time = datetime_date.strftime('%-I:%M %p')
        
    context = {
        'games': games,
        'game_date': game_date,
        'game_time': game_time
    }

    return render(request, 'games/games.html', context)
```

```html
    {% for game in games %}    
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 mb-4">
              <div class="gamecard p-2">
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                             <h3 class="game-summary white opacity-90 text-center font-800 mb- 
                                       0">{{ game.summary }}
                             </h3>
                             <p class="white opacity-90 mb-0 text-center">
                                   {{ game_date }} 
                                   {{ game_time }}
                             </p>
                             <p class="white opacity-90 mb-2 text-center"><small>
                                {{ game.venue.name }} - {{ game.venue.city }},
                                {{ game.venue.state }}</small>
                             </p>
                        </div>    
                  </div>    
                     
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello sir, the game model has the game_date and game_time fields? The value is always the same because you are setting 'game_date': game_date and the game_date is a value not a list or a propertie

Comment: The dates are essentially being run through a for loop twice. Once so I can format it in my view and then again in my template. I'm not sure how to format and pass it through otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your loop, in the view:

```
for game in games:
    date = game['schedule']['date']
    datetime_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    game_date = datetime_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
    game_time = datetime_date.strftime('%-I:%M %p')
```

you are continually *overwriting* the value of the variables `game_date` and `game_time`), (also `date` and `datetime_date`, but those don't matter as they're only temporary values that you don't use outside the loop), and so on. So inevitably, when you access it later - in the template, as it happens - it has the value calculated from the last element of the `games` array.

From your template, you clearly don't want these to be single variables holding a single value each - you want them to exist, with different values, for *each* element of the list. Since each `game` is clearly a dictionary anyway, the simplest way to do this is to simply add data to those dictionaries with the properties you need.

```
for game in games:
    date = game['schedule']['date']
    datetime_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    game['game_date'] = datetime_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
    game['game_time'] = datetime_date.strftime('%-I:%M %p')
```

and then in the template, rather than

```
{{ game_date }}
{{ game_time }}
```

use it like this:

```
{{ game.game_date }}
{{ game.game_time }}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh... you're a genius! Thank you so much, worked like a charm :)

Answer (score -1):

Pass your date without formatting and then in your template try this..

```
{{game_date|date 'd-m-Y'}}
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it comes through as a string and Django cant format it.

Comment: Why do you format as string? When you can use it as date object

Comment: It comes from the dictionary as a string. I have to format it as a datetime object and that is where I was having the problem.

Comment: Ok. Format and then try my answer in the templates.